# Trying to understand SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE enumeration

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, terminal-services

I'm struggling to understand all of the [SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380129) values:

```
typedef enum _SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE { 
  Interactive              = 2,
  Network,
  Batch,
  Service,
  Proxy,
  Unlock,
  NetworkCleartext,
  NewCredentials,
  RemoteInteractive,
  CachedInteractive,
  CachedRemoteInteractive,
  CachedUnlock
} SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE, *PSECURITY_LOGON_TYPE;
```

I'm trying to understand them in the context of a C++ code like this, that lists all logon sessions:

```
//Error handling is skipped!
ULONG n = 0;
LUID* pluid;
LsaEnumerateLogonSessions(&n, &pluid);

for(ULONG s = 0; s < n; s++)
{
    PSECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA* ps;
    LsaGetLogonSessionData(&pluid[s], &ps);

    //Analyze logon type
    ps->LogonType;

    LsaFreeReturnBuffer(ps);
}

LsaFreeReturnBuffer(pluid);
```

So far I can understand these:

1. `Interactive` if the actual (human) user logged in to the workstation. (As we are now while viewing this page.)
2. `RemoteInteractive` if a [Remote Desktop Connection](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/remote-desktop-connection) has been established with this workstation.

Can someone add more description to other values?

Comment: The MSDN page you link to has a reasonable description of all the values.  Which values are you having problems with?

Comment: @EricBrown: I'm obviously asking since I don't understand the MSDN explanation. For instance, what is `batch process` or how is `CachedInteractive` different from `Interactive`, just to name a few. If you know what they all mean, wouldn't it be easier to post an actual explanation versus what you posted above or not post anything at all?

Comment: CachedInteractive uses cached credentials, for example if domain controller is inaccessible.

Comment: @c00000fd - and I'm trying to figure out what you don't understand about the MSDN explanation.  I suspect there may be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, as well.

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN explanations are all pretty self-explanatory, with the following clarifications:

1. `CachedXXXX` - Don't ask the domain controller to validate; instead, check against the local cached copy of the credentials.
2. `Batch` - Scheduled Tasks run using the Batch logon type.  [You can deny the Batch Logon right, which would prevent a user from running scheduled tasks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457125.aspx).